# Python crashing while calculating SHA-1 hashs for large files in Windows OS

Tags: python, hash, large-files, sha1

I am wondering if I could have some fresh eyes on this python script.  It works fine with small and medium size files but with large ones (4-8GB or so) it inexplicable crashes after running for a couple of minutes.

[Zipped script here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3150177/Programming/Python/Source%20code/SHA-1/SHA-1HashGen.zip)

Or:

```
import sys
import msvcrt
import hashlib

#Print the file name (and its location) to be hashed  
print 'File:  ' + str(sys.argv[1])

#Set "SHA1Hash" equal to SHA-1 hash
SHA1Hash = hashlib.sha1()

#Open file specified by "sys.argv[1]" in read only (r) and binary (b) mode
File = open(sys.argv[1], 'rb')

#Get the SHA-1 hash for the contents of the specified file
SHA1Hash.update(File.read())

#Close the file
File.close()

#Set "SHA1HashBase16" equal to the hexadecimal of "SHA1Hash"
SHA1HashBase16 = SHA1Hash.hexdigest()

#Print the SHA-1 (hexadecimal) hash of the file
print 'SHA-1: ' + SHA1HashBase16

#Make a blank line
print ' '

#Print "Press any key to continue..."
print 'Press any key to continue...'

#"Press any key to continue..." delay
char=0
while not char:
    char=msvcrt.getch()
```

*** Updated ***

Working python script for calculating SHA-1 hash of large files.  Thanks goes to Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams for pointing out what was wrong and Tom Zych for the code.

[Zipped source here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3150177/Programming/Python/Source%20code/SHA-1/SHA-1HashGen%28working%29.zip)

To use simply drag and drop the file to be hashed on top of script.  Alternatively you can either use a command prompt with the usage of:

```
SHA-1HashGen.py Path&File
```

Were SHA-1HashGen.py is the file name of the script and Path&File is the path and file name of the file to be hashed.

Or drop the script in to the SendTo folder (in Windows OS; shell:sendto) to get it as a right click option.

Comment: The terminal window just closes instantly in the middle of calculating the hash.

Comment: For what is worth: you should try launching your python script from a command prompt. That way'll get an more information on the error.

Comment: @Winston Ewert yes your right, sorry I usually do though I slipped up this time.

Comment: Another method is to run it from a batch file and put `pause` after it (it sounds like you're using Windows).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Stop reading the file in one go; you're consuming all the memory on the system. Read in 16MB or so chunks instead.

```
data = File.read(16 * 1024 * 1024)
```

Comment: That's what I thought originally but when I checked I still had +2GB left.

Answer (score 9):

(In response to Peter's comment that 2 GB are left.)

I suspect Ignacio is right nonetheless. Try replacing the read/update line with this:

```
while True:
    buf = File.read(0x100000)
    if not buf:
        break
    SHA1Hash.update(buf)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help your solution worked nicely, its so simple I feel stupid for post to begin with and not figuring it out myself ;)

Comment: Sure if you really want me to, it was a close tie but I thought your answer was better for some poor brain dead programmer who will google the something at some point in the future so I went with it.